# Tying to add a percentage to a calculation of 2 UITextFields

Tags: swift

I am using Swift 5 and I am relatively a novice and self taught at 60 it not easy to get the answers but here goes- I have 2 textfields one value is already passed from another view controller, then I have an Item cost field and a button to calculate these fields ok this works fine, but what I wish to do is have another textfield entry that I can add a markup percentage so for example textfield 1 has 50 and textfield 2 I enter 3, I would then like to add a markup value of say 4% so when I calculate these fields I get a total plus the markup percentage that's been added

I can get everything to work but can't find a way to add that pesky markup

```
import UIKit

class CostingsViewController: UIViewController {

    //Item Cost entered into this field
    @IBOutlet weak var itemCost: UITextField!
    //Markup value entered into here
    @IBOutlet weak var markUP: UITextField!
    //This value is passed to this viewcontroller from another veiwcontroller
    @IBOutlet weak var newLabel: UILabel!
    //This value is calculated on the IBAction
    @IBOutlet weak var totalCost: UITextField!
    var finalName = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

     newLabel.text = finalName

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func calculateCost(_ sender: Any) {
       //Enter the markUP calculation here



        totalCost.text = String(format: "%.2f",Double(newLabel.text!)! * Double(itemCost.text!)!)

      self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

```
totalCost.text = String(format: "%.2f",Double(newLabel.text!)! * Double(itemCost.text!)!)
```

this works just fine but the Mark up I can't seem to get it to work - ive checked out lots of tutorials but seems to be many ways but none suit what I am trying

Comment: What is the value in `newLabel`? I’m guessing a quantity or something like that, but it’s unclear from your question.

Comment: @Rob A perfect example of why good variable names are important.

Answer (score 0):

If you can say

```
totalCost.text = String(format: "%.2f",Double(newLabel.text!)! * Double(itemCost.text!)!)
```

Then you can say

```
let v1 = Double(newLabel.text!)!
let v2 = Double(itemCost.text!)!
let v3 = // do your math here
totalCost.text = String(format: "%.2f", v3)
```

I'm not condoning your code; I'm just saying that you shouldn't have any difficulty breaking it into pieces so that you can manipulate the Double values more easily.

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for the information I get this and it works just fine thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, it you want to add `4%` to a value, it means multiplying it by `1.04`.

That means:

```
let itemCost = Double(itemCost.text!)!
let markUp = Double(markUP.text!)!

let total = itemCost * (1 + markUp / 100)
totalCost.text = String(format: "%.2f", total)
```

As a side note, please, use `NumberFormatter` to convert numbers to a string and viceversa, especially when we are talking currencies.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation of the grand total is:

```
// the total, not rounded (e.g. if there was one item at a unit price of 0.10 and 3% markup (i.e. 0.03), this `unrounded` will have 0.103)

let unrounded = Double(quantity) * unitPrice * (markUp + 1.0) 

// You might then round that value to two decimal places, like so:

let grandTotal = (unrounded * 100.0).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) / 100.0
```

---

That having been said, I would suggest a few other things:

1. You may notice that in the above, I’m not referencing UIKit controls like text fields and labels. You really want to delineate between the “model” (the prices, quantities, the total, etc.) and the “view” (the text fields, the labels, etc.).

   - The view objects generally, by convention, include a suffix that indicates the type of view object. So you might have `markUpTextField` or `quantityLabel`. This way, you not only won’t confuse them with the corresponding model values, but you can clearly tell what sort of object it is.
   - As you update a text field, you should update the model. E.g. as you change the `markUpTextField`, you update the `markUp` numeric model object.
   - When you’re calculating the total, you should calculate it from the model objects only. You shouldn’t be referencing any `UIKit` objects.

   This isn’t absolutely critical, but it’s an extremely good habit to get into as it’s a central tenet of MVC (and MVVM and MVP and ...) programming patterns. The benefits of this really come into play when you eventually start using table/collection views where your UIKit controls are reused for visible items and no longer are reliable sources of information. It will also be extremely useful when you start getting into unit testing of your code, and you pull business logic out of your view controllers and move them into some mediating object like a “view model” or what have you.
2. You should avoid using `String(format:)` to create strings for the UI. Instead, use `NumberFormatter`. That solves two problems:

   - You want to accept and produce “localized” numbers in your UI. E.g., in Germany, they write a number of one million to two decimal places as `1.000.000,00`. In India, it can be `10,00,000.00`. Etc. By using `NumberFormatter`, you minimize the amount you have to code to deal with all of these international formats.
   - If you use a `NumberFormatter` with a `numberStyle` of `.percent` for your markup value, it will do the necessary division by `100` for you.
3. You may want to set the `delegate` of the `UITextField` objects to be your view controller (which you can do either in IB or programmatically) and then have a `UITextFieldDelegate` extension to your view controller whose `shouldChangeCharactersIn` will accept the change only if the resulting text can be changed to a number using the above formatters.

   You might also want a `textFieldDidEndEditing` that formats the entered value nicely when the user is done.

---

Reflecting the above observations, you end up with something like:

```
class CostingsViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var quantityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var markUpTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: Model objects

    var quantity: Int?  { didSet { updateTotal() } }
    var price: Double?  { didSet { updateTotal() } }
    var markUp: Double? { didSet { updateTotal() } }
    var total: Double?  { didSet { totalLabel.text = priceFormatter.string(for: total) } }

    // MARK: Private formatters

    private var priceFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter
    }()

    private var quantityFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        return formatter
    }()

    private var percentFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .percent
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // I'm going to set these here, but maybe these were supplied by the presenting view controller

        quantity = 3
        price = 1000
        markUp = 0

        // update the UI controls

        quantityLabel.text = quantityFormatter.string(for: quantity)
        priceTextField.text = priceFormatter.string(for: price)
        markUpTextField.text = percentFormatter.string(for: markUp)
        totalLabel.text = priceFormatter.string(for: total)
    }
}

private extension CostingsViewController {
    private func updateTotal() {
        // calculate total
        let quant = quantity ?? 0
        let cost = price ?? 0
        let percent = markUp ?? 0
        let unrounded = Double(quant) * cost * (percent + 1.0)

        // round the result
        let rounded = (unrounded * 100.0).rounded(.toNearestOrAwayFromZero) / 100.0

        // update our model
        total = rounded
    }
}

extension CostingsViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // some useful constants
        let decimalSeparator = priceFormatter.decimalSeparator ?? "."
        let percentSymbol = percentFormatter.percentSymbol ?? "%"

        // figure out what the string value will be after replacing the characters
        let oldText = textField.text ?? ""
        let updateRange = Range(range, in: oldText)!
        let text = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: updateRange, with: string).filter(("01234567890" + decimalSeparator).contains)

        // update the appropriate model object
        switch textField {
        case priceTextField:
            if text == "" {
                price = 0
                return true
            } else if let value = priceFormatter.number(from: text)?.doubleValue {
                price = value
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }

        case markUpTextField:
            if text == "" {
                markUp = 0
                return true
            } else if let value = percentFormatter.number(from: text + percentSymbol)?.doubleValue {
                markUp = value
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }

        default:
            return true
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        switch textField {
        case priceTextField:  textField.text = priceFormatter.string(for: price)
        case markUpTextField: textField.text = percentFormatter.string(for: markUp)
        default:              break
        }
    }
}
```

---

A further refinement: When creating data types to hold the prices, I’d advise against using binary floating points like `Float` or `Double`. These types cannot actually perfectly capture fractional decimal values. I’d use `Decimal` type instead. This will help avoid rounding problems that can result if you start adding up many binary floating point values.

If you do that, you end up with something like:

```
class CostingsViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var quantityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var markUpTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: Model objects

    var quantity: Int?   { didSet { updateTotal() } }
    var price: Decimal?  { didSet { updateTotal() } }
    var markUp: Decimal? { didSet { updateTotal() } }
    var total: Decimal?  { didSet { totalLabel.text = priceFormatter.string(for: total) } }

    // MARK: Private formatters

    private var priceFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
        return formatter
    }()
    private var quantityFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        return formatter
    }()
    private var percentFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .percent
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.generatesDecimalNumbers = true
        return formatter
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // I'm going to set these here, but maybe these were supplied by the presenting view controller

        quantity = 3
        price = Decimal(1000)
        markUp = Decimal(0)

        // update the UI controls

        quantityLabel.text = quantityFormatter.string(for: quantity)
        priceTextField.text = priceFormatter.string(for: price)
        markUpTextField.text = percentFormatter.string(for: markUp)
        totalLabel.text = priceFormatter.string(for: total)
    }
}

private extension CostingsViewController {
    private func updateTotal() {
        // calculate total
        let quant = Decimal(quantity ?? 0)
        let cost = price ?? Decimal(0)
        let percent = markUp ?? Decimal(0)
        var unrounded = quant * cost * (percent + Decimal(1))

        // round the result
        var rounded = Decimal()
        NSDecimalRound(&rounded, &unrounded, 2, .bankers)

        // update our model
        total = rounded
    }
}

extension CostingsViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        // some useful constants
        let decimalSeparator = priceFormatter.decimalSeparator ?? "."
        let percentSymbol = percentFormatter.percentSymbol ?? "%"

        // figure out what the string value will be after replacing the characters
        let oldText = textField.text ?? ""
        let updateRange = Range(range, in: oldText)!
        let text = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: updateRange, with: string).filter(("01234567890" + decimalSeparator).contains)

        // update the appropriate model object
        switch textField {
        case priceTextField:
            if text == "" {
                price = Decimal(0)
                return true
            } else if let value = priceFormatter.number(from: text)?.decimalValue {
                price = value
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }

        case markUpTextField:
            if text == "" {
                markUp = Decimal(0)
                return true
            } else if let value = percentFormatter.number(from: text + percentSymbol)?.decimalValue {
                markUp = value
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }

        default:
            return true
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        switch textField {
        case priceTextField:  textField.text = priceFormatter.string(for: price)
        case markUpTextField: textField.text = percentFormatter.string(for: markUp)
        default:              break
        }
    }
}
```

---

Finally, as I alluded to above, we’d generally like to get a lot of this code out of the view controller (using MVVP or MVP or whatever). That’s beyond the scope of this question, but I mention it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Hi Rob way beyond my understanding of how to get a percentage of a value but thank you anyway